# .End(xlUp).Row to external file

Tags: excel, vba

I use now the following macro in my worksheet:

```
With Sheets("missing_artikels")
        .Range("A1:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
```

Instead of copy the data to the local file, i want copy the data to a external file on location `I:\sales\Funnel\funnel.xls` in worksheet "funnel".

How can i combine this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might come to you as a funny advice but the beauty is never in writing complex codes but in writing simple codes which you can understand even if you are looking at it after say 1 year down the line :)

Always break up your code in simple understandable lines. For example I have combined your request with your existing code. I have declared the relevant variables (*See for getting the lastrow, sheet names etc*)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Const wbPath = "I:\sales\Funnel\funnel.xls"

Sub Sample()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsILrow As Long, wsOLrow As Long

    '~~> Input Workbook
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("missing_artikels")

    '~~> Output Workbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("funnel")
    wsOLrow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With wsI
        wsILrow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:F" & wsILrow).Copy wsO.Range("A" & wsOLrow)
    End With

    '
    ' '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

HTH